# Alertify.confirm throws uncaught in promise error?

Tags: javascript, promise, angular-promise, es6-promise

I'm using JS promises to convert alerify's confirm method to return a `promise`.

Without going into details, the confirm function is something like this:

```
alertify.confirm = function(message onOk, onCancel) ...
```

This basically displays a confirmation alert and based on whether the user clicks `ok` or `cancel` button the respective `onOk` or `onCancel` functions are called.

So anyway, I've wrapped this function in a `Promise` like this in my main app:

```
function confirm(text) {
   return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
     alertify.confirm(text, resolve, reject);
   }
}

var promise = confirm('Are you sure?');
promise.then(function() { alert('you clicked ok'); });
```

This works as expected but if I click `Cancel` then I get this error in console:

`Uncaught (in promise)`

I think it is because I'm not adding a `.catch` to my promise and then alertify calls the `reject` function. How do I check if the reject function is assigned or not?

Also what would be the proper way to do this?

```js
function submit() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //how to check if reject is assigned or not?
    confirm('Are you sure') ? resolve() : reject();
  });
}

function test() {
  var promise = submit();
  promise.then(() => alert('you clicked ok'));  
  promise.catch(() => alert('you clicked cancel'));
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="test">
```

Comment: Promise rejections are for errors only IMO. I would resolve the promise for both OK and Cancel with a true/false boolean value.

Comment: Please show all relevant code. Need a [mcve] to be able to help troubleshoot

Comment: @RyanZim Oh okay that does makes sense. I'll probably do that if there is no other solution. It's just that I just want to call the `.then` function only if the user clicks okay because I generally don't care when the user clicks cancel. If only there was a way to see if `reject` was assigned or not?

Comment: @charlietfl added minimal code sample to reproduce the error. When you click test => cancel, you will see the error "uncaught in promise" in your browser's **console**.

Comment: works fine for me in firefox. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Google chrome. It just throws an error in the developer console.

Comment: @supersan If you really don't care about cancel, then yeah, you can use reject for that. You will probably need to use a dummy `catch` to suppress the console error.